# Window > Preferences Missing in Android Studio after Update

Tags: android-studio

I have Updated Android Studio (Windows). And now I cannot find Window > Preferences any more. Did they move it? And what I the way to open the preferences now?

Answer (score 16):

click on File > Settings
it's the replacement to Window > Preferences

Comment: Then what? Lots of Settings.

Comment: @DSlomer64 look on left panel for the options you want

Comment: "Left panel" meaning what? Of what? My question(s) are 1.6 to 2.8 years old. I don't remember what I was trying to find and my question is so badly worded (incomplete) that I can't tell from what I wrote, either. But if you're talking about File > Settings, that's the previous Answer, but apparently I didn't know where to go from there in 2017 and today I don't know what I wanted to do back then. However, I think File > Settings is the logical place to look for a LOT of things, probably including whatever I wanted back then,